# What does the question count include?

Tags: support, design

At the time of writing this there where 64,202 questions according to the figure given on the questions-newest tab. What does this number represent, is it the total number of questions on the website, the total number of unique questions (i.e. so that duplicates aren't included), does it include questions closed or put on hold etc?

Comment: @Normal Human: Why not, sir, convert it into an answer rather than a comment?